# Can I open/repair this Duplo pullback motor?

Tags: duplo, repair

My son has a [Duplo pullback motor](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/2318_Pullback_Motor).

[image]

This motor does not work well. After pull back it moves forwards 2 and a half wheel turns and stops. There is a small resistance forcing it forward two millimeters it makes a louder click and then the wheels rotate again 2 and a half turns to stop again. After forcing 2 mm it continues again and again until the spring is loose.

As there are no screws to open it and fix the mechanism I don't know how to open and fix it.

Can anyone give a tutorial to open it non destructive and fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Some Lego assemblies like this are welded together or otherwise permanently assembled. Usually the best you can do is cut them where there are seams, then glue them back together. Or, if that seems like too much work, [buy a replacement on Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=duppull&name=Duplo%20Car%20Base%202%20x%206%20Pullback%20Motor%20with%20Yellow%20Wheels,%20Black%20Tires&category=%5BDuplo,%20Vehicle%5D#T=S&C=5&O=%7B"color":5%7D)